# Combinatorial analysis with JS: Find combinations of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the main array "arr":

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And the "options" arrays:

```
let optArr1 = [1,3]
let optArr2 = [2,4,3]
let optArr3 = [1,4,2]
let optArr4 = [5]
let optArr5 = [2,3,4,5]
```

How to get all the possible combinations of "options" that actually fulfill all the numbers in the main array? The result I need is as follows:

```
combination1 = [optArr1, optArr2, optArr4]
combination2 = [optArr1, optArr2, optArr5]
combination3 = [optArr1, optArr2, optArr3, optArr4]
combination4 = [optArr1, optArr2, optArr3, optArr5]
combination5 = [optArr1, optArr3, optArr5]
combination6 = [optArr2, optArr3, optArr4]
combination7 = [optArr2, optArr3, optArr5]
```

I've run out of ideas of wether write a condition to stop trying new combinations or to actually write a function that performs the combinatorial analysis.

For clarification:

I'm not trying to get the code DONE by anyone else. Some light shed on how to tackle a combinatorial problem from a code pov is more than sufficient.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: The easy but maybe-sloppy way would be to generate all set combinations of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then check which permutations, with their associated array values put together, satisfy the full `arr`.

Comment: Hi, @31piy. Besides trying to bruteforce the solution with Math.random to start from a different options index and calling the function recursively n times... I'm currently trying to reduce the time complexity of the function.

I tried to simplify the post in order to have a cleaner explanation; I'm sorry if indirectly I made it look like if I didn't have any additional details on this.

Answer (score 0):

An unoptimized brute force approach by checking the values of a temporary array with the options.

> As result, you get an array (here with just the indices of the `options` array) with all combinations for getting all values of the `values` array.
>
> ```
> [
>     [0, 1, 2, 3],
>     [0, 1, 2, 4],
>     [0, 1, 3],
>     [0, 1, 4],
>     [0, 2, 3],
>     [0, 2, 4],
>     [0, 3, 4],
>     [0, 4],
>     [1, 2, 3],
>     [1, 2, 4],
>     [2, 3, 4],
>     [2, 4]
> ]
> ```

```js
function getCombinations(values, options, size) {

    function fork(temp, index) {
        var itemSet = new Set;
        temp.forEach(a => a.forEach(v => itemSet.add(v)));
        if (itemSet.size === values.length) {
            result.push(temp);
            return;

        }
        if (index >= values.length) {
            return;
        }

        fork(temp.concat([options[index]]), index + 1);
        fork(temp, index + 1);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork([], 0);
    return result;
}

var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    options = [[1, 3], [2, 4, 3], [1, 4, 2], [5], [2, 3, 4, 5]];

console.log(getCombinations(values, options, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you are required call concat function . Here, I have made concat method. But I am not sure if it really match . Here, I have give one example for ecombination1

```
ecombination1 = optArr2.concat(optArr3).concat(optArr4);
```